# Application wont write to MS DB

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I have created a Java desktop application which reads and should write to a Microsoft Access DB.

The application works fine before I convert it to a `.JAR` after which it can only read from the DB but doesn't write to it.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace or any other infomation?

Comment: The most likely reason an MDB goes read only would be because the directory it's housed in doesn't have the correct permissions.

Comment: Jet/ACE requires the data file be in a Windows file system. Period. End of statement.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you've included the database file in the JAR file itself. Simply put, although you can get a URL to *read* a file from inside a JAR, you can't write to one. You're going to need to take the database (MDB file?) out of the JAR and put it in on the actual filesystem if you want to write to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 

Indeed before the MDB was inside, but now the MDB file is outside the Jar File. I might have solved the problem, I was snooping around and found that there is a certain group of users in windows called INTERACTIVE, if I give that group full control, the JAR can write to it otherwise nada. Now its time to test on other systems.

Comment: You might set-up the DB in a sub-directory of `user.home`.  It is easy to find using system properties, x-plat. and stable across runs.  It should also have write enabled for the user.  BTW - does the app. have a GUI (e.g. Swing, AWT, SWT)?  If so, [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) might be a good installation option.  JWS offers the `ExtensionInstallerService` that will be called before (1st time) application launch.  Here is my little [demo. of the `ExtensionInstallerService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).