# Using dsnless connection in Java: how to get URL of db inside a jar file and how to put db into jar

Tags: java, jdbc, dsn, jdbc-odbc

I know how use dsnless to access a DB out of jar file, but I need to get url of db inside the jar file with using dsnless connection(i don't know it is possible or not).

I have tried the following code

```
String a=getClass().getResourceAsStream("/homedei.mdb").toString();

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+a,"","");
```

and also this

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+ new File("homemedi.mdb").getAbsolutePath(),"","");
```

and also this.

I see this in youtube to insert img files in jar file and create a class file as below

```
import java.io.InputStream;
final public class ResourcesProvider 
{
    public static InputStream load(String path)
    {
        InputStream input=ResourcesProvider.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
        if(input==null)
        {
            input=ResourcesProvider.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+path);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

and try to

```
String a=ResourcesProvider.load("/homemedi.mdb").toString();

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+a,"","");
```

All the above arise in `NullPointerException`

I don't have clear idea about `getSource()` or `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`

Can you also explain in child words?

i already read this link:
[Application wont write to MS DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404559/application-wont-write-to-ms-db)

i want to know how can i get url of db into string or anyother method

thanks

Comment: Short hint: the "files" in a JAR are not really files. Unless the tool you use knows how to access them (Swing and most Java libraries do!), they can't access them. So if you need MS Access to be able to read the file, you'll need to copy it to a temporary location first.

Comment: i need msacces db inside the jar file i dont understand this "you'll need to copy it to a temporary location first"

Comment: Then read the question I linked to.